# why your connection to this site is not private

Tags: wordpress

While login into WordPress admin. It shows a popup with a username and a password fields saying that connection is not private.

I have googled it but I couldn't find any effective solutions.

[image: window frame with border]
This above is the screenshot of problem.

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDQZG.jpg

Comment: i found the solution. paste this code at last of .htaccess file: <filesmatch "wp-login.php"> Satisfy Any </filesmatch>. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: window frame with border]
This above is the screenshot of problem.

**solution:**
paste below code in your .htaccess file of wordpress. It worked for me.

```
<filesmatch "wp-login.php"> 
Satisfy Any 
</filesmatch>
```